# Multiple Laravel 5 Paginations within the same page

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I have a container that I want to fill with items from my database, say every row has these columns:

```
$item->title
$item->description
$item->color
$item->id
```

I have a `main-container` where I want to loop through all of my items, but only 5 at a time. I know I can have all of them, but I really want there to be no scrolling.

I know for a whole page you would just replace `->get();` with `->paginate(x);` where `x` is the number of items you want to show per page.

But I also have a `secondary-container` where I want to loop through a bunch of other items, but I wouldn't know how to implement the second one, since the `main-container` would work when the url extends `?page=x` where x is the nth chunk of items iterated.

Would I be able to have a custom `get` url request (not sure about the term, correct me if I'm wrong) and do something like `?page2=x` for my `secondary-container`?

I searched arround but didn't quite know how to put my question into a small answer, and the results weren't helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did the answers below help?

Comment: I was asleep, I'm gonna try yours very soon, thanks for answering! @jszobody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `paginate` method:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L429

You see that it accepts a `$pageName` variable, which tells it which request variable to use.

So you can do this:

```
MyModel::where(...)->paginate(20, ['*'], 'fooPage');
```

And Laravel will use `$request->fooPage` for the page variable.

Or, you can see the paginate method also allows you to just explicitly pass in the page variable itself as the fourth parameter:

```
MyModel::where(...)->paginate(20, ['*'], null, $request->myPageVar);
```

And now a GET variable `?myPageVar=1` will set the page.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly :)